# Check for default value of attribute in XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

i have XML schema:

```
<xsd:complexType name="contactsType">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="contact" type="contactType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:attribute name="visible" type="xsd:boolean" default="true"/>
</xsd:complexType>
```

and i want to find all contacts which have @visible=true,

```
//contacts[@visible='true']
```

but this expression doesn' t return nodes without set @visible like this:

```
<contacts />
```

so i want to know if there is any function in XPath which returns also default values of attributes

Thanks

Jan

Answer (score 0):

You need a schema-aware processor like [Saxon-EE](http://saxon.sourceforge.net).

Comment: Thanks for answer. I need it as match pattern for XSL transformation so Saxon-EE is not solution, but it s good to know :)
I hacked it like this 

//contacts[@visible='true' or not(@visible)]

Althought I don' t like this solution very much.